# Reindex and Interpolate data

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have the following data frame.

```
index = [0.018519,  0.037037,   0.055556,   0.074074,   0.092593,   0.111111,   0.12963,    0.148148,   0.166667,   0.185185,
     0.203704,  0.222222,   0.240741,   0.259259,   0.277778,   0.296296,   0.314815,   0.333333,   0.351852,   0.37037,
     0.388889,  0.407407,   0.425926,   0.444444,   0.462963,   0.481481,   0.5,    0.518519,   0.537037,   0.555556,   0.574074,
     0.592593,  0.611111,   0.62963,    0.648148,   0.666667,   0.685185,   0.703704,   0.722222,   0.740741,   0.759259,   0.777778,
     0.796296,  0.814815,   0.833333,   0.851852,   0.87037,    0.888889,   0.907407,   0.925926,   0.944444,   0.962963,   0.981481,   1]
y = [1.5,   2,  6,  23.5,   112,    158.5,  226,    332,    354.5,  376.5,  420.5,  479.5,  513,    513.5,  515.5,  516,    519.5,  523,
 525.5, 527.5,  531,    536,    541,    542,    542,    545.5,  547,    553,    553.5,  555,    555.5,  555.5,  555.5,  556,    556.5,  557,
 561,   564.5,  571,    586,    589.5,  589.5,  590,    590.5,  591.5,  592,    592.5,  592.5,  594,    595.5,  604.5,  606,    608,    608.5]

df = pd.DataFrame(y, index=index).astype(float)
```

I want to reindex and interpolate the y values based on a new index
I tried the following:

```
new_index= pd.Index([0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1])
df= df.reindex(new_index).interpolate(method='values')
print (df)
```

It successfully reindex the data frame but still give NaN values.

```
print (df)
0.1    NaN
0.2    NaN
0.3    NaN
0.4    NaN
0.5  547.0
0.6  559.3
0.7  571.6
0.8  583.9
0.9  596.2
1.0  608.5
```

Note that all interpolation methods did not work, does anyone know how to get interpolated y values for the new index?

Thanks

Comment: What is your expected result? Note that if you only do `df = df.reindex(new_index)`, there are only 2 valid values. I don't think that is what you want?

Comment: I expected to get interpolated y values for each of the new indexes. For example, for the "0.1" new index, the y value will be a linear interpolated value of y values for the "0.092593" and "0.111111" index in the original data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it:

```py
# Add new values
df = pd.concat(
    [df, pd.DataFrame(data=[pd.NA for _ in range(len(new_index))], index=new_index)]
)

# Remove duplicated indices, sort, interpolate and get rid of values not in new_index
df = (
    df.loc[~df.index.duplicated(keep="first"), :]
    .sort_index()
    .interpolate(method="values")
    .reindex(new_index)
)
```

Then:

```py
print(df)
# Output
0.1  130.599498
0.2  411.699525
0.3  516.700038
0.4  534.000054
0.5  547.000000
0.6  555.500000
0.7  563.799962
0.8  590.100005
0.9  593.400016
1.0  608.500000
```